# How to port the package from one distro to another?

Tags: ros, catkin-package, ros-fuerte, nodes, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a package [here](https://github.com/AlexTape/EddieRead) which solves my problem but the package was built in Fuerte. Is it possible to port it to Indigo, if so how can i do it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214195/how-to-port-the-package-from-one-distro-to-another?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to port your nodes to catkin:

http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amrac](https://answers.ros.org/users/23079/amrac/) on 2015-07-21**:
I have the same issues with package on groovy.
Christian, do you mean that using caktin somehow resolve the port from different distro?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-21**:
No, he means that you should *update* the package to use catkin for building it instead of rosbuild. The migration guide shows you how to perform that update. Updating the build scripts is only part though: any incompatibilities in APIs used will also have to be resolved.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-21**:
Doesn't indigo still support rosbuild? So catkinizing isn't strictly necessary. However, all API changes will have to be adapted. There are usually migration guides for each new release. Check these out for all revisions in between to see how to resolve possible errors.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-21**:
@dornhege: yes, rosbuild should still be supported in Indigo, but it will require two workspaces and overlays. I just wanted to clarify what @cyborg-x1 meant with 'you have to port your nodes to catkin', as asked by @Amrac.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-21**:
I would recommend catkinizing to prevent these issues. For porting it might be easiest to see if a rosbuild works, first.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-22**:
Yep that's it getting rid of rosbuild and use catkin instead will save you headaches I guess ...
-> **You can not depend from a catkin package to a rosbuild package** (should say enough)
So whenever you have a message defined in the rosbuild package you need in a catkin pkg ... good luck... ;-)